# if motherboard fails, SSD on Raid array can be used in another

Tags: raid, software-raid

I have two Servers of different motherboard but same CPU  architecture and lithography. I have setup raid 1 in both Server with 2 SSDs in each. Server 2 is for backup and snapshot purpose.

If server 1 fails ( Motherboard Hardware issue ), can i use 2 SSDs of *Server 1* in *Server 2* for data recovery?

How efficient Software raid 1 in today's CPU (i have 12 Cores, 24 Threads),  does it affect performance of System ?

Comment: Usually, if you have the exact same hardware you can "reuse" your RAID1 disks in the second machine and boot up the same system. I write _usually_ because I would never ever ever ever count on it for data protection purposes, that's what backups are for. Your second question is really another one to ask, but: IMO other than in I/O-heavy tasks, your software (or hardware) RAID1 shouldn't noticeably affect performance.

Comment: motherboard Models and configuration are different on both server...

Comment: Then there is no other answer than: you have to try it. There are so many different drivers / controllers / OSs / etc., you can't tell for certain.

Answer (score 2):

Different cases:

- Fake RAID on cheap SOHO motherboards. 
  These are called fake RAID because they don't have dedicated chips to control the RAID, this is all done in software by the CPU. Can usually only be read on the exact class of  hardware again, with the correct drivers installed. They are also quite unreliable. Avoid like the plague.
- Dedicated RAID controller as addon card or onboard on server grade main boards. 
   
  These *usually* can be read on other servers, provided that the same line of RAID controllers is in the new server. No guarantees though, check with the vendor.
- Pure software RAID.
   These can be used on any system with the same operating system without any problem, often even wit older versions to a certain degree.  On modern systems, the performance impact is very small and mostly non-noticeable.  I am using this exclusively these days because they are by far the least hassle and most reliable. Server breaks down? Just use any machine without the worry about the RAID...